# Prisma dynamic table names - findMany error

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma

I am trying to create a function that receives a dynamic table name and select all its data using Prisma in NestJS with typescript.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Prisma } from '@internal/prisma/client';
import { PrismaService } from 'src/prisma/prisma.service';

@Injectable()
export class DbMigrationService {
  constructor(
    private readonly prisma: PrismaService,
  ) {}

  migrateTables() {
    this.getTableData(Prisma.ModelName.user);
  }

  async getTableData(tableName: Prisma.ModelName) {
    const data = await this.prisma[tableName].findMany();
    console.log(data);
  }
}
```

The problem is that typescript throws this error:

```
error TS2349: This expression is not callable.
  Each member of the union type '(<T extends saldoFindManyArgs>(args?: SelectSubset<T, saldoFindManyArgs>) => CheckSelect<T, PrismaPromise<saldo[]>, PrismaPromise<...>>) | ... 50 more ... | (<T extends tipo_cabeloFindManyArgs>(args?: SelectSubset<...>) => CheckSelect<...>)' has signatures, but none of those signatures are compatible with each other.

37     this.prisma[tableName].findMany();
```

What would be the best way to resolve this?

Comment: Does it work if you just pass a static value in tableName, let's say if you have a User model, then does this.prisma['user'].findMany() work as expected?

Comment: There is a related Stack Overflow answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767052/dynamic-table-names-prisma-typescript-error Does that help?

Comment: @NurulSundarani it does work passing a static value. But the you provided answer it has nothing to do with my problem :/

Comment: Hey man, have you found out? Same problem here

Comment: @DaniloMourelle hey! I have not found a solution. I used abstraction creating repositories to retrieve the data. For example, if I have a Person table I implement a repository with all the methods I need to CRUD and just use this repository whenever I need it

Comment: Given that `this.prisma['user'].findMany()` works, it's probably erroring because the type of tableName is too broad, post the type and a sandbox-

Answer (score 0):

I decided it like this

```
const tableName = req.params.tableName;
const data = await prisma[`${tableName}`].findMany();
```

Comment: Didn't work for me on version 4.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume there is `countOf` function.

```
const countOf = async (modelName: Uncapitalize<Prisma.ModelName>) => {
  const count: number = await (prisma[modelName] as any).count();
  return count;
};
```

I looked up a lot of information about this, but in the end it gets very complicated if you don't use `any`.

I am not sure that this is really the only correct way.

But It works 100% and also shows a static type error if you entered a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, it work because the `any` silver bullet.... But it loses tracking of type in returned value

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing(. in this.prisma.[tableName])

```
async getTableData(tableName: Prisma.ModelName) {
    const data = await this.prisma.[tableName].findMany();
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Comment: Actually no, using the bracket notation there's no dot before the brackets. The problem is related to the return types I believe